# List all records in crystal reports, even if missing fields

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I really need to make a full list of every record in our database. The problem is that if the record is missing a phone number or an address, crystal reports doesn't print it.

Phone number and address aren't necessarily always inputted in our database, but I definitly need all records included on this report, even if those fields are missing.

I really have no idea how to get these missing records included in the report, but when I delete the Phone column I see a lot of the missing records appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are making `inner joins` for the tables which populate that data.. for these type of requirements it is suggested to use `outer joins` on the tables that have all data... so that you can get all records if some other tables doesn't have the required information

Answer (score 3):

Check your joins first. Make sure that you are not linking by either of those 2 fields.

Also check your format session to see if there is any suppression condition. Sometimes when copying behavior between reports, those conditions are left behind from the previous report.